# Select where multiple conditions in parallel lists of values

Tags: sql, logical-operators, presto

Say I have two lists of values:

```
values1 = (1, 2, 3)
values2 = (10, 20, 30)
```

Is it possible to do a select along the lines of this:

```
SELECT 
    id_1, 
    id_2, 
    id_3 
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    (id_1 IN values1 OR id_2 in values1)
    AND id_3 IN values2
```

This should only return results when one of the following is true:

```
(id_1 = 1 OR id_2 = 1) AND id_3 = 10
(id_1 = 2 OR id_2 = 2) AND id_3 = 20
(id_1 = 3 OR id_2 = 3) AND id_3 = 30
```

and not:

```
(id_1 = 1 OR id_2 = 1) AND id_3 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could express this using a table of constants and a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (values (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)) v(x, y)
     on v.x in (t.id_1, t.id_2) and v.y = t.id_3 ;
```

Or you can simplify your filtering using `in`:

```
(1 IN (id_1, id_2) AND id_3 = 10) OR
(2 IN (id_1, id_2) AND id_3 = 20) OR
(3 IN (id_1, id_2) AND id_3 = 30)
```